# Castle.Core for WindowsPhone71

Tags: .net, nuget, castle-dynamicproxy

I would like to use the DynamicProxy from Castle.Core, but I can not because:

```
PM> Install-Package Castle.Core
    Installing 'Castle.Core 3.2.2'.
    Successfully installed 'Castle.Core 3.2.2'.
    Adding 'Castle.Core 3.2.2' to foo.
    Uninstalling 'Castle.Core 3.2.2'.
    Successfully uninstalled 'Castle.Core 3.2.2'.
    Install failed. Rolling back...
    Install-Package : Could not install package 'Castle.Core 3.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files th
    at are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package Castle.Core
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I read:

> To use Castle DynamicProxy you need the following environment: one of
>   the following runtimes installed .NET version 3.5 sp1 or newer
>   Silverlight version 4 or newer Castle.Core.dll (assembly where DynamicProxy lives)

I do not understand.
Does someone have experience about this? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is not support any more by Windsor. If I'm correct WP71 is a silverlight platform. You could try Windsor 3.1. This version should still support silverlight. (see: http://www.castleproject.org/blog/2012/08/windsor-and-core-3-1-released/)